# Angular16 Observable not being dispatched correctly

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement authentication on my Angular App, but I'm struggling with the update of an Observable. It's really weird, 'cause it doesn't work only for one case, when I test (with a button for example), the subscribing is good. Logout is working just fine, but login is not ; it log the user and redirect, but app.component doesn't get the Observable update, I need to reload the page to actually have the user

Here is the code :

**auth.service.ts**

```
constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(USER_STORAGE_KEY)!)
    );
    this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .post<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}${this.apiRoutes.LOGIN}`, {
        email,
        password,
      })
      .pipe(
        map((user) => {
          localStorage.setItem(USER_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
          this.userSubject.next(user);
          return user;
        })
      );
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem(USER_STORAGE_KEY);
    this.userSubject.next(null);
    this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
  }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // Reset errors
    this.error = '';

    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.authService
      .login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe({
        next: (user: any) => {
          console.log('user:');
          console.log(user);
          console.log('navigate');
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          this.error = error;
          this.loading = false;
        },
      });
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.user.subscribe((user) => {
      console.log('user received');
      console.log(user);
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
```

Comment: How is the AuthService provided? Do you ever see the `'user received'` log from the app.component subscription?

Comment: AuthService is provided by the constructor. Yep, I seed the user received on logout for example, or when I try with a random button that generates a new user. The only case which is not working is on login oO

Comment: I was wondering how is the AuthService ... provided, not injected. Do you have `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`? When it is not provided by the root injector, then you should be able to find it in the `providers` array on one of your modules. You should find out if there's any probability that you have multiple instances of this service. One that has the user, and one that doesn't.